# Need help with file server

Tags: server, nas

I need to know the cheapest but best quality server that can host data (not games) for a college esports team. it will mostly be used for holding game files and documents for the team. I do not have access to Windows Server and am trying to make it work on Windows 10.

Comment: Could you please post more specific requirements? And the best solution is to rent a VPS in a general use case. It's more expensive but saves **a lot** of trouble.

Comment: Well it has to be a physical server due to the College policies, its going to be used for file storage and transfer mostly it wont be used to host games just store them as of right now but my question is what type of server as in CPU speed and ram would be the best to use

Comment: Any old machine which can run your OS of choice will do. But it's better to get dedicated hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your comments you are looking for a [Network Attached Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). Instead of buying a regular PC, buy a dedicated device, like [one of these QNAP NASes](https://www.qnap.com/en/product/series/home).

If you absolutely must do it yourself any PC which can run your OS of choice would suffice for a small team. What you may want if you are going with Windows is to get a motherboard which supports RAID and use it.